# Правильно проверить количество символов в input type='number'

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

Есть input с type='number'. В этом инпуте я проверяю количество введенных символов через length. Вводить в такой инпут можно цифры и точку, чтобы была дробь. Но проблема в том, что вводя точку, в инпуте что-то ломается, и он начинает показывать, что в него введено 0 символов. А если после точки вводить еще символы, то подсчет возобновляется в нормальном режиме. Почему так происходит и можно ли это исправить как-то?

```js
let input = document.getElementById('inp');
let par = document.getElementById('par');
input.oninput = function() {
  par.innerHTML = 'Symbols entered: ' + input.value.length;
}
```

```html
<input id='inp' type="number">
<p id='par'>Symbols entered: 0</p>
```

Comment: да пусть ноль кажет в этот момент, все равно число с точкой в конце не валидное, и дальше ввод продолжится. Или нет? Только добавить возможно надо input.value.split('.').join('').length; Чтоб точки не считались

Comment: Это особенность данного типа инпутов, тк они не расчитанны на числа, заканчивающиеся на точку

Comment: @Voprositel не особенность, а локализация. В русском применяется запятая, а не точка. Если ввести валидную запятую, все будет нормально. Даже на цифровой клавиатуре при переключении раскладки меняется ` . / , `

Comment: Использовать обычный `type="text"` и не париться `input.value = input.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id='inp' type="number">
```

Возможно потому что тут стоит тип число, и после точки оно начинает воспринимать как число потому что видит дробь, попробуй поставить string а не number.

Это чисто мое мнение.

Comment: type string у инпута нет, но есть text. просто хочется сделать через number, т.к для телефонов оно открывает окошко, где только цифры